useState doesn't work . useEffect show alltime []
I use React and i want add film tittle in array, but i can't do it and show in UI. Please help me. I watched a similar question and in my opinion there is no answer to my question. alert work's right. but useEffect all time shows empty array. Watch my code and write answer please :)
import {useEffect, useState} from 'react';

import {OneFilm} from "./OneFilm";
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import {Film} from "../../interfaces";
import styles from '../../css/AllFilms.module.css';


export function AllFilms() {
    const [allFilms, setAllFilms] = useState<Film[]>([]);
    const [selectedFilms, setSelectedFilms] = useState<string[]>([])

    const fetchFilms = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await fetch(`URL`, {
                headers: {
                    'X-API-KEY': process.env.REACT_APP_TOKEN
                }
            });
            const dataResp = await response.json();
            setAllFilms(dataResp);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Ошибка при получении фильмов:', error);
        }
    };

    const selectFilm = (filmTitle: string) => {
        alert(filmTitle)
        setSelectedFilms(prev => [...prev, filmTitle])
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchFilms()
    }, [])

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(selectedFilms)
    }, [selectedFilms])

    return (
        <div className={styles.container}>
            <ul className={styles.films}>
                {
                    allFilms.map((film) => (
                            <Link to={`/id=${film.id}`} key={film.id} onClick={() => selectFilm(film.name)}>
                                <OneFilm film={film}/>
                            </Link>
                        )
                    )}
            </ul>

            <div className="selected__films">
                <ul>
                    {selectedFilms.map((film) => (
                        <li>{film}</li>
                    ))}
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

Maybe it's doent't work because i redirect in another page?

Your goal isn't clear. Why are you setting state if you're redirecting to a different page? Those two actions contradict each other

@BrianThompson I want to determine on the "All Movies" page which movies the user clicked on

Your components (AllFilms) state is lost when the component is not rendered anymore. From the docs:

React preserves a component’s state for as long as it’s being rendered
at its position in the UI tree. If it gets removed, or a different
component gets rendered at the same position, React discards its
state.

Therefore your array gets deleted everytime, you navigate away from the page that shows your component, which usually happens when a link is clicked.

do u know how it can fix? redux?

@VueFrontend I think redux should work as it acts like a global state afaik, but I never used it so far. You could also save the array client-side as a browser-cookie. You would have to convert it to a string first, for example with JSON.stringify(). I did that once using the npm-package react-cookies.
